# Strongloop controller in cluster mode results in EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, rest, strongloop, loopbackjs

I'm building an API with Strongloops's Loopback. I'm following [this tutorial](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Create+a+simple+API) and so far it's working when I run the app with

```
slc run
```

However, if I try to run the app in clustered mode (to take advantage of a dual core server) the second process throws an EADDRINUSE error.

My config.json reads

```
{
    "restApiRoot": "/v1",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 5000,
    "url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000/"
}
```

much like in the example (except for the port). I haven't been able to find documentation of how (or if) should I modify this config.

Has anyone ran slc in cluster mode?
Does anyone have experience on running Node in clustered mode? (I know foreman allows something like this).

Thanks!

Comment: Is line [33 to 44 included](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-app/blob/master/server/server.js) in your server.js ? Seems like the spawned workers are attaching to same port as server.

Comment: Yes, my app has those exact lines. I created the app with ```slc loopback``` but that part is identical to the example app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What command did you use to run the app in a cluster?

You should use something like

```
slc run --cluster cpus
```

See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/SLC/slc+run for docs.  I just ran the app from https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-datasourceAPI.git with this command and it ran OK for me.

BTW, docs for config.json are in http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/config.json.

Rand

Comment: I was using that same command. Then I tried in my localhost and it ran fine (with 4 cpus). I restarted the dev server and tried again and now it's running. So I guess it was a zombie process after all. Thanks!

Comment: [Tech support](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/1999-08-04/) from Dilbert comics over a decade ago.

Comment: I must admit I freak out when I have to reboot an EC2 instance. Half the time the little freaks get locked in a bootloop due to the ephemeral storage failing to automount.  At least the new T2 instances don't have any.